# Django - Is it possible to prefetch multiple filters of a single field for a queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I know you can prefetch a single filtered queryset E.g.

```
Parent.objects.all()
.prefetch_related(
  Prefetch("child_set", queryset=Child.objects.filter(type="A")
)
```

That way running `obj.child_set.all().count()` will return the `count` of related `A` `Child`s without running another query.

But what if I wanted to have the `B` count too? So the following would take 2 queries - can I somehow prefetch them both?

```
return {
  "a_count": obj.log_set.filter(type="A").all().count(),
  "b_count": obj.log_set.filter(type="B").all().count(),
}
```

**Edit:**
I've tried

```
Parent.objects.all()
.prefetch_related(
  Prefetch("child_set", queryset=Child.objects.filter(type="A"),
  Prefetch("child_set", queryset=Child.objects.filter(type="B")
)
```

But that gives me the following error when I try to access the object:

```
{
    "detail": "Not found."
}
```

Comment: `count()` actually does another query, so prefetch won't help. You'd want to use `len` instead, so `len(obj.log_set.filter(type="A").all())`. About the `"Not found."`error, that seems to be unrelated with the prefetch. If you remove the prefetch I'm pretty sure you would still see the error

Comment: But with regards to your main question, yes its possible to prefetch the same field and assign them on different attributes, by using `to_attr`. More details [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects)

Comment: Thanks - the `to_attr` was what I was looking for. If you add an answer I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regards to your main question, you can use [**`Prefetch`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) object on the same field with different filters, but assign them with different `to_attr` values like this:

```py
from django.db.models import Prefetch


Parent.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        "child_set", 
        queryset=Child.objects.filter(type="A"), 
        to_attr="child_set_a"
    ),
    Prefetch(
        "child_set", 
        queryset=Child.objects.filter(type="B"), 
        to_attr="child_set_b"
    ),
)
```

Comment: Hm actually I'm getting the `Not found` error when I try this. When I remove the `prefetch` completely or if I simply leave one `Prefetch()` in there, the error goes away. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you share your views?